# Motor powered on and brakes disengaged for three days, should I be worried?

Tags: dc-motor

I have a brushless DC motor which runs at 24v which I left on for three days without noticing. The motor just has a ssi motor feedback. The motor was not running as the software which commanded it was off. However, the brakes were wired to another power supply, which I also left on.

During my motor tuning process I noticed that the motor gets pretty hot near the end close to the brakes. I was able to spin the motor after the tuning.

When I came back to the setup 3 days later, the brakes felt just as hot. I could still see that the brake was pulling current, around .2A, which was nominal. When I tried to spin the motor, it gave me a following error. I tried to re-phase and then retune the motor, but its behavior has been rather erratic. Now, I've left it to cool down completely before I do anything. But, I'm concerned that I might have damaged something.

Has anyone left a motor on for way too long?

EDIT: update, after waiting for the motor to cool, it seems to have worked again. Strange, I'm still a bit uneasy about this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very high chance you have demagnetized the rotor.

Permanent magnets have something called Curie Temperature: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature

If you take a magnet to its specific curie temperature it will lose its permanent magnetism.

It can easily be checked by backdriving the rotor of the motor at a given speed and measuring the terminal voltage that is generated.

You should have the machines voltage constant \$k_e\$ to then calculate what the voltage should be via:  \$V = k_e\omega \$  (careful about how \$k_e\$ is defined, peak phase or peak line-line).

I haven't personally demagnatised a machine like this, but a technician on a project of mine did when they forgot to disengage a poweroff brake (slip torque around 30Nm) and accelerated the machine from 0rpm to 10,000 over 30seconds on a rig that could generate in excess of 30Nm at 10,000.